# Upload files to S3 Bucket directly from a url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

We need to move our video file storage to AWS S3. The old location is a cdn, so I only have url for each file (1000+ files, > 1TB total file size). Running an upload tool directly on the storage server is not an option.

I already created a tool that downloads the file, uploads file to S3 bucket and updates the DB records with new HTTP url and works perfectly except it takes forever.

Downloading the file takes some time (considering each file close to a gigabyte) and uploading it takes longer.

Is it possible to upload the video file directly from cdn to S3, so I could reduce processing time into half? Something like reading chunk of file and then putting it to S3 while reading next chunk.

Currently I use System.Net.WebClient to download the file and AWSSDK to upload.

PS: I have no problem with internet speed, I run the app on a server with 1GBit network connection.

Comment: I would recommend trying spin up an EC2 instance ( with a big pipe ) or multiple instances and do your export from there.

Comment: I dont know why I didnt think this before, I got 100 mbit/sec download speed from CDN and ~300 Mbit/sec upload speed into S3 and looks like the whole transfer will be done in ~12 hours. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been answered by me in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662286/1895871), here's the gist:

```
object = Aws::S3::Object.new(bucket_name: 'target-bucket', key: 'target-key')
object.upload_stream do |write_stream|
  IO.copy_stream(URI.open('http://example.com/file.ext'), write_stream)
end
```

This is no 'direct' pull-from-S3, though. At least this doesn't download each file and then uploads in serial, but streams 'through' the client. If you run the above on an EC2 instance in the same region as your bucket, I believe this is as 'direct' as it gets, and as fast as a direct pull would ever be.

Comment: This is not _direct_ upload from a URL.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov correct - there's no way to 'instruct' S3 to pull 'directly' without detour via a client. This solution at least doesn't download-then-upload, but streams via a client. An EC2 instance in the same region as your bucket IMHO would be as direct as it gets. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

No, there isn't a way to direct S3 to fetch a resource, on your behalf, from a non-S3 URL and save it in a bucket.

The only "fetch"-like operation S3 supports is the [PUT/COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) operation, where S3 supports fetching an object from one bucket and storing it in another bucket (or the same bucket), even across regions, even across accounts, as long as you have a user with sufficient permission for the necessary operations on both ends of the transaction.  In that one case, S3 handles all the data transfer, internally.

Otherwise, the only way to take a remote object and store it in S3 is to download the resource and then upload it to S3 -- however, there's nothing preventing you from doing both things at the same time.

To do that, you'll need to write some code, using presumably either asynchronous I/O or threads, so that you can simultaneously be receiving a stream of downloaded data and uploading it, probably in symmetric chunks, using S3's [Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) capability, which allows you to write individual chunks (minimum 5MB each) which, with a final request, S3 will validate and consolidate into a single object of up to 5TB.  Multipart upload supports parallel upload of chunks, and allows your code to retry any failed chunks without restarting the whole job, since the individual chunks don't have to be uploaded or received by S3 in linear order.

If the origin supports [HTTP range requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233), you wouldn't necessarily even need to receive a "stream," you could discover the size of the object and then `GET` chunks by range and multipart-upload them.  Do this operation with threads or asynch I/O handling multiple ranges in parallel, and you will likely be able to copy an entire object *faster* than you can download it in a single monolithic download, depending on the factors limiting your download speed.

I've achieved aggregate speeds in the range of 45 to 75 Mbits/sec while uploading multi-gigabyte files into S3 from outside of AWS using this technique.

Comment: I ended up with using an EC2 instance to run the download&upload tool for fast transfer but your way is definitely a solution for my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if a proxy ( node express ) is suitable for you then the portions of code at these 2 routes could be combined to do a *GET* *POST* fetch chain, retreiving then re-posting the response body to your dest. S3 bucket.

[step one](https://github.com/rowntreerob/sampleexpress/blob/master/app.js#L66)  creates response.body

[step two](https://github.com/rowntreerob/sampleexpress/blob/master/app.js#L180)

set the stream in 2nd link to response from the GET op in link 1 and you will upload to dest.bucket the stream ( arrayBuffer ) from the first fetch