# How to upload file in AWS S3 Bucket through endpoint in ASP.NET Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I am using ASP.NET Core and AWSSDK.S3 nuget package.

I am able to upload file by providing **accessKeyID**, **secretKey**, **bucketName** and **region**

Like this:

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretKey);

   using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
   {
       var request = new PutObjectRequest
       {
             AutoCloseStream = true,
             BucketName = bucketName,
             InputStream = storageStream,
             Key = fileName
       }
   }
```

But I am given only an **URL** to upload file

```
11.11.11.111:/aa-bb-cc-dd-useast1
```

How to upload file through the URL? I am new to AWS,I will be grateful to get some help.

Comment: Look like asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458590/upload-files-to-s3-bucket-directly-from-a-url)..

Comment: @TuanVA Not exactly, I will upload the file from application itself. I need to know how ti use AWS VPC enpoint for S3

Comment: Just enable S3 Endpoint, then network with do the rest.

Comment: I need to find some code in .net core. The endpoint is enabled. I am not sure how to write the code using the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class UploadFileMPUHighLevelAPITest
    {
       private const string bucketName = "*** provide bucket name ***";
       private const string filePath = "*** provide the full path name of the file to upload ***";
        // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;
        private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;

        public static void Main()
        {
            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
            UploadFileAsync().Wait();
        }

        private static async Task UploadFileAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var fileTransferUtility =
                    new TransferUtility(s3Client);  
                // Option 1. Upload a file. The file name is used as the object key name.
               await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName);
               Console.WriteLine("Upload 1 completed");

             }
         }
      }
    }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

You can use the provided access point in place of the bucket name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TPutObjectRequest.html

Comment: If you are given a url, then u guess thats the access point to the bucket. Replace the bucketname with the access point.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try and let you know

Comment: Hi, I am getting error: "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'" I think if  i am given access this should work. ANy thoughts?

Comment: Yes. The app should have credentials of the aws account in the web config or in the code

Comment: Thanks. I am new in AWS, have very little knowledge.